# Looking for a story about spacemen landing on Earth who turn out to be caterpillar like aliens

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I read a short story in an anthology paperback many years ago, perhaps 25-30 years, during a plane ride. The stories were probably already old at that time. It is never made clear what the spacemen who land near a small town look like. You get the idea they are humans as they carefully explore a town, trying not to be discovered. They kept to the trees or in heavy vegetation. They may have been looking for things to fix their spaceship. The final scene has them stretching up to their glorious alien grub or caterpillar like appearance and height, the first time we get a physical description of them. I would love to read it again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  How long ago was "many years?"  Minor details like that can help people find a good match.  You should check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good questions and [edit] in any additional details you think of.

Comment: Thanks for your help.